# Receiving error upon attempting to pass message to background.js:

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined

Background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
if(message[message.length - 1] === true)
    {
        var AFArray = message; 
        sendResponse({farewell: AFArray});
    }
if(message === "request")
    {

        sendResponse({farewell:"TEsting!"});
    }});
```

Content Script:

```
function AFCopy()
{
    var AFArrayCount = 0;
    var AFArray = [];
    //cycle over classes and apply label to array.
     while(AFArrayCount <4)
         {
             if(document.getElementsByClassName("_xd6")[AFArrayCount])
                 {
                     AFArray[AFArrayCount] = document.getElementsByClassName("_xd6")[AFArrayCount].getAttribute("LABEL"); 

                     AFArrayCount++;
                 }

         }
    //assign copy signature 
    AFArray.push(true);
    //test array is constructed correctly
    console.log(AFArray);

    //send array to background.js
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: AFArray}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);});
}
```

This function is running on an onClick event.

Comment: Also attempted to replace the if statements within the background.js with just plain " sendResponse({"Test!"}); ". This did not work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `message` you are sending is: `{greeting:AFArray}` and that object is what your listener receives.

Therefore `message[message.length - 1]` makes little sense.

It should be something like `message.greeting[message.greeting.length - 1]`